# Java Spring похожие справочники как упростить создание?

Tags: java, spring, table

Суть такая есть таблицы и к таблицам привязаны дополнительные таблицы и эти другие таблицы очень часто имеют одинаковые поля, например:

```
Товары   -> Вид товара
Клиент  -> Статус клиента
Оплата  -> Тип оплаты
и т.п.
```

Вид товара / Статус клиента / Тип оплаты -> у этих таблиц одинаковые поля типа ‘id’ и ‘наименование’

Я каждый раз создаю новые таблицы и по сути дублирую различные методы, думаю, что это не совсем правильно и есть более быстрые и правильные варианты.

Вопрос, как правильно организовать эти таблицы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял хранить лучше в отдельных таблицах не смотря на то, что данные похожи

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать сущность "Справочник". Их хранить ваши однотипные сущности там.
В структуре наподобие этой

```
|id|parent_id|name            |
| 1|null     |Вид товара      |
| 2|1        |Вид товара #1   |
| 3|1        |Вид товара #2   |
| 4|null     |Статус клиента  |
| 5|4        |Статус клиента#1|
```

Если появляется нужда достать всё с одним типом, просто достаёте всё с нужным parent_id.